# Problem rendering pointer gauge on all tree nodes

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree

I'm using the D3.js tree to render a gauge for each node. Only the root node is rendering the gauge pointer (path object). I researched several sources to try to understand the problem, but I couldn't identify the cause.

My goal in this example is to display the pointer to all nodes, using the Json "pointerValue" property to position the pointer. Thank you all for your attention.

this is my code

```html
<html>
<style>

    g.arc {
      fill: steelblue;
    }

    g.pointer {
      fill: #e85116;
      stroke: #b64011;
    }

    g.label text {
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      fill: #666;
    }

    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .node text:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #ccc;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }
</style>

<body>

    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function deg2rad(deg) {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function newAngle(d) {
        var ratio = scale(d);
        var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
        return newAngle;
    }

    function centerTranslation(r) {
        return 'translate('+ r +','+ r +')';
    }

    var config = {
        size                        : 100,
        clipWidth                   : 100,
        clipHeight                  : 60,
        ringInset                   : 20,
        ringWidth                   : 20,

        pointerWidth                : 10,
        pointerTailLength           : 5,
        pointerHeadLengthPercent    : 0.8,

        minValue                    : 0,
        maxValue                    : 100,

        minAngle                    : -90,
        maxAngle                    : 90,

        transitionMs                : 3000,

        majorTicks                  : 5,
        labelFormat                 : d3.format('d'),
        labelInset                  : 10,

        arcColorFn                  : d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
    };

    range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
    r = config.size / 2;
    pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);


    scale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0,1])
        .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);

    ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
    tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {return 1/config.majorTicks;});

    var arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
    .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
    .startAngle(function(d, i) {
        var ratio = d * i;
        return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
    })
    .endAngle(function(d, i) {
        var ratio = d * (i+1);
        return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
    });

    var lineData = [ [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
                     [0, -pointerHeadLength],
                     [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
                     [0, config.pointerTailLength],
                     [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0] ];

    let treeData =
      {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Root",
        "pointerValue": "10",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Node x",
            "pointerValue": "55",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "2",
                "name": "Node y",
                "pointerValue": "75"
              },
              {
                "id": "3",
                "name": "Node z",
                "pointerValue": "95"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Node w",
            "pointerValue": "35"
          }
        ]
      };


// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

    // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
    var treeData = treemap(root);

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
    links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 400});

    // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

    // Update the nodes...
    var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            //alert(d.data.name);
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        }).on('click', click);

    nodeEnter.append('text')
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("x", d => d.children || d._children ? 50 : -55)
          .attr("y", -5)
          //.attr("id", function(d) {
                //alert(d.data.id);
          //    return "node-" + d.data.id;
          //})
          .attr("text-anchor", d => d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start")
          .text(d => d.data.name);

    //#########################################################################

    var vis = nodeEnter.append('svg')
            //.attr("id", function(d) {
            //    return "gauge-" + d.data.id;
            //})
            .attr('class', 'gauge')
            .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
            .attr('height', config.clipHeight)
            .attr("y", -70)
            .attr("x", -50);

    var arcs = vis.append('g')
            //.attr("id", function(d) {
            //    return "arc-" + d.data.id;
            //})
            .attr('class', 'arc')
            .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));
    arcs.selectAll('path')
            .data(tickData)
        .enter().append('path')
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
            })
            .attr('d', arc);

    var lg = vis.append('g')
            //.attr("id", function(d) {
            //    return "label-" + d.data.id;
            //})
            .attr('class', 'label')
            .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));
        lg.selectAll('text')
            .data(ticks)
        .enter().append('text')
            .attr('transform', function(d) {
                var ratio = scale(d);
                var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
                return 'rotate(' + newAngle +') translate(0,' +(config.labelInset - r) +')';
            })
            .text(config.labelFormat);

    var pg = vis.append('g')
            .data([lineData])
            .attr('class', 'pointer')
            .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));

    //########################################
    //THIS PART JUST WORKS FOR ROOT NODE
    //########################################

    var ratio = scale(87);
    var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);

    pg.append('path')
        //d attribute that defines its shape and position.
        .attr("d", d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear) )
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(' +config.minAngle +')')
            .transition()
            .duration(config.transitionMs)
            .ease(d3.easeElastic)
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + newAngle +')');

//#########################################################################

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either append each data array to the `<path>`s using `datum` or, if you want to use `data`, create a proper enter selection:

```
var pg = vis.selectAll(null)
    .data([lineData])
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr('class', 'pointer')
```

Here's your code with that change:

```html
<html>
<style>
  g.arc {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
  g.pointer {
    fill: #e85116;
    stroke: #b64011;
  }
  
  g.label text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    fill: #666;
  }
  
  .node {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .node circle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 3px;
  }
  
  .node text {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .node text:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function deg2rad(deg) {
      return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    function newAngle(d) {
      var ratio = scale(d);
      var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
      return newAngle;
    }

    function centerTranslation(r) {
      return 'translate(' + r + ',' + r + ')';
    }

    var config = {
      size: 100,
      clipWidth: 100,
      clipHeight: 60,
      ringInset: 20,
      ringWidth: 20,

      pointerWidth: 10,
      pointerTailLength: 5,
      pointerHeadLengthPercent: 0.8,

      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 100,

      minAngle: -90,
      maxAngle: 90,

      transitionMs: 3000,

      majorTicks: 5,
      labelFormat: d3.format('d'),
      labelInset: 10,

      arcColorFn: d3.interpolateHsl(d3.rgb('#e8e2ca'), d3.rgb('#3e6c0a'))
    };

    range = config.maxAngle - config.minAngle;
    r = config.size / 2;
    pointerHeadLength = Math.round(r * config.pointerHeadLengthPercent);


    scale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([0, 1])
      .domain([config.minValue, config.maxValue]);

    ticks = scale.ticks(config.majorTicks);
    tickData = d3.range(config.majorTicks).map(function() {
      return 1 / config.majorTicks;
    });

    var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(r - config.ringWidth - config.ringInset)
      .outerRadius(r - config.ringInset)
      .startAngle(function(d, i) {
        var ratio = d * i;
        return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
      })
      .endAngle(function(d, i) {
        var ratio = d * (i + 1);
        return deg2rad(config.minAngle + (ratio * range));
      });

    var lineData = [
      [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0],
      [0, -pointerHeadLength],
      [-(config.pointerWidth / 2), 0],
      [0, config.pointerTailLength],
      [config.pointerWidth / 2, 0]
    ];

    let treeData = {
      "id": "0",
      "name": "Root",
      "pointerValue": "10",
      "children": [{
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Node x",
          "pointerValue": "55",
          "children": [{
              "id": "2",
              "name": "Node y",
              "pointerValue": "75"
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "name": "Node z",
              "pointerValue": "95"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "name": "Node w",
          "pointerValue": "35"
        }
      ]
    };


    // Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 90,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 90
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" +
        margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var i = 0,
      duration = 750,
      root;

    // declares a tree layout and assigns the size
    var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

    // Assigns parent, children, height, depth
    root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) {
      return d.children;
    });
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;

    // Collapse after the second level
    root.children.forEach(collapse);

    update(root);

    // Collapse the node and all it's children
    function collapse(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children
        d._children.forEach(collapse)
        d.children = null
      }
    }

    function update(source) {

      // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
      var treeData = treemap(root);

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
        links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.y = d.depth * 400
      });

      // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

      // Update the nodes...
      var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
          //alert(d.data.name);
          return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        }).on('click', click);

      nodeEnter.append('text')
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("x", d => d.children || d._children ? 50 : -55)
        .attr("y", -5)
        //.attr("id", function(d) {
        //alert(d.data.id);
        //    return "node-" + d.data.id;
        //})
        .attr("text-anchor", d => d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start")
        .text(d => d.data.name);

      //#########################################################################

      var vis = nodeEnter.append('svg')
        //.attr("id", function(d) {
        //    return "gauge-" + d.data.id;
        //})
        .attr('class', 'gauge')
        .attr('width', config.clipWidth)
        .attr('height', config.clipHeight)
        .attr("y", -70)
        .attr("x", -50);

      var arcs = vis.append('g')
        //.attr("id", function(d) {
        //    return "arc-" + d.data.id;
        //})
        .attr('class', 'arc')
        .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));
      arcs.selectAll('path')
        .data(tickData)
        .enter().append('path')
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
          return config.arcColorFn(d * i);
        })
        .attr('d', arc);

      var lg = vis.append('g')
        //.attr("id", function(d) {
        //    return "label-" + d.data.id;
        //})
        .attr('class', 'label')
        .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));
      lg.selectAll('text')
        .data(ticks)
        .enter().append('text')
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
          var ratio = scale(d);
          var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
          return 'rotate(' + newAngle + ') translate(0,' + (config.labelInset - r) + ')';
        })
        .text(config.labelFormat);

      var pg = vis.selectAll(null)
        .data(d => [d])
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('class', 'pointer')
        .attr('transform', centerTranslation(r));

      //########################################
      //THIS PART JUST WORKS FOR ROOT NODE
      //########################################

      var ratio = scale(87);
      var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);

      pg.append('path')
        //d attribute that defines its shape and position.
        .attr("d", d3.line().curve(d3.curveLinear)(lineData))
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(' + config.minAngle + ')')
        .transition()
        .duration(config.transitionMs)
        .ease(d3.easeElastic)
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
          var dataPointerValue = d.data.pointerValue;
          var ratio = scale(dataPointerValue);
          var newAngle = config.minAngle + (ratio * range);
          return 'rotate(' + newAngle + ')';
        });

      //#########################################################################

      // UPDATE
      var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

      // Transition to the proper position for the node
      nodeUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
        });

      // Update the node attributes and style
      nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
        .attr('r', 10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        })
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer');

      // Remove any exiting nodes
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
        })
        .remove();

      // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
      nodeExit.select('circle')
        .attr('r', 1e-6);

      // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
      nodeExit.select('text')
        .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

      // ****************** links section ***************************

      // Update the links...
      var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
        .data(links, function(d) {
          return d.id;
        });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        });

      // UPDATE
      var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

      // Transition back to the parent element position
      linkUpdate.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          return diagonal(d, d.parent)
        });

      // Remove any exiting links
      var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr('d', function(d) {
          var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
          }
          return diagonal(o, o)
        })
        .remove();

      // Store the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });

      // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
      function diagonal(s, d) {

        path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

        return path
      }

      // Toggle children on click.
      function click(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d.children = null;
        } else {
          d.children = d._children;
          d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```